# Having trouble with pointers and classes. Two identical classes, where one works and one deosn't

Tags: c++

Okay, so I'm having a bit of trouble with a project I've been working on. I need two classes to form a linked list of multi variable classes (or structs). The first one, called gps is working fine. It's supposed to read in x and y coordinates into a location, and then add that to a linked list. This works totally fine, seen below:

```
ifstream in;
location *tail = NULL;
location *head = NULL;

gps::gps()
{
    tail = NULL;

    in.open("coordinates.txt");
    if(in.fail())
    {
        std::cout << "Unopen to open coordinates.txt" << std::endl;
    }
    while (!in.eof())
    {
        getLocation();
    }
    in.close();
}

void gps::getLocation()
{
    location o;
    in >> o.xcoordinate;
    in >> o.ycoordinate;
    addToTail(o);
}

void gps::addToTail(location a)
{
    location *newlocation = new location();
    newlocation->xcoordinate = a.xcoordinate;
    newlocation->ycoordinate = a.ycoordinate;
    newlocation->next = NULL;

    if (tail == NULL)
    {
        head = tail = newlocation;
    }
    else
    {
        tail->next = newlocation; // now the next of old tail is the new location
        tail = newlocation;       // the new location should become the new tail
    }
}
```

So this all works fine, but now I need an identical one to do the same thing but it must make a linked list of accelerations (x, y and z), values read from a file. However, it gets as far as to return the first set of coordinates before crashing. Looking at the two classes, they seem identical with the location and acceleration classes just being used to store the data. Why does the first work, while the second doesn't? I feel like the error is coming from my pointer system, but I can't figure out what's wrong with it.
Here is the sensor class, where the problem is coming from:

```
ifstream in_2;

sensor::sensor()
{
    acceleration *head = NULL;
    acceleration *tail = NULL;



    in_2.open("acceleration.txt");
    if(in_2.fail())
    {
        cout << "Unopen to open acceleration.txt" << std::endl;
    }
    while (!in_2.eof())
    {
        getAcceleration();
    int f;
    cin >> f;
    }
    in_2.close();
}

void sensor::getAcceleration()
{
    acceleration o;
    in_2 >> o.x;
    in_2>> o.y;
    in_2>>o.z;
    addToTail(o);
}

void sensor::addToTail(acceleration a)
{
    acceleration *newacceleration = new acceleration();
    newacceleration->x = a.x;
    newacceleration->y = a.y;
    newacceleration->z = a.z;
    newacceleration->next = NULL;
    cout << a.x <<a.y<<a.z;
    if (tail == NULL)
    {
         head = tail = newacceleration;
    }
    else
    {
        tail->next = newacceleration; // now the next of old tail is the new location
        tail = newacceleration;       // the new location should become the new tail
    }

}
```

I feel like the error lies somewhere around the line "cout << a.x << a.y << a.z;" because this line does print the correct values. Hope someone can help show me what's going on here! Been stuck for a long time.

EDIT:

accelaration.txt:

```
1 1 1
0 7 11
1 7 10
2 6 40
1 7 -33
0 7 12
```

coordinates.txt:

```
    53.344384 -6.261056
    53.344424 -6.260818
    53.344450 -6.260614
    53.344476 -6.260324
    53.344501 -6.260088
    53.344537 -6.259906
```

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger?

Comment: Add some lines of your input files to the question

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because you haven't provided real code to attempt to debug.

Comment: I can give you the whole code if you want? I don't really know what you're asking. I'm not good at debugging, not something we covered in college, it's a basic coding module.

Comment: please add code of acceleration, at least that we can see the types of x,y,z and also the wrong values that you mentioned you see in the cout line.

Answer (score 2):

You have

```
newacceleration->y = a.y;
```

Twice. The 2nd one needs to be:

```
newacceleration->z = a.z;
```

Update: What ere these 2 lines in sensor()?

```
int f;
cin >> f;
```

Comment: This is a classic case where [rubber ducking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) would help a lot.

Comment: Sorry! That was a typo in the post, not the code. Thanks for pointing it out.